# INDEX по полю datetime MySQL (производительность)

Tags: дата, связи, индексы, производительность, mysql

Доброго времени суток!
Нужна консультация матерых людей в SQL

Представьте есть такая БД:
3 таблицы news, rels, rubircs

```
news: n_id, n_publ_date (datetime, естественно дата более менее однородна и поле добавлено в индекс)
rubrics: r_id
rels(нужна для связи многие-ко-многим): parent_id, children_id  (оба поля проиндексированы)
```

допустим есть 40к, а может быть и гораздо больше, новостей, три рубрики и нам нужно выбрать 10 новостей отсортированных по дате публикации, принадлежащих 3ей рубрики, мы пишем:

```
SELECT n_id, n_publ_date 
FROM `news`, `rels` 
WHERE r_parent_id = n_id AND r_children_id = 3 
ORDER BY n_publ_date DESC 
LIMIT 10

время выполнения запроса на моем компе 0.0667, если выполнить explain, то sql скажет что index n_publ_date не задействован, а используются только первичные ключи id'шники

к таблицы `news` добавляем FORCE INDEX (n_publ_date) и о чудо время выполнения запроса 0.0005, т.е. в 100 раз быстрее, при этом explain показывает что задействован индекс n_publ_date
```

Вы скажете что разница не большая, но на деле оказывается колоссальная, особенно если проект реальный и в таблицах присутствует множество полей, таблицы весят десятки мегабайт . При таком раскладе, если не используется индекс по дате, то конечная выборка получается очень большая и не влезает в оперативную память, тогда чудесный MySQL начинает копировать ее на диск, а это, в свою очередь, может занимать десятки секунд.

Что можно сделать, что бы MySQL в любом случае цеплял index по дате без force index? Или нужно смотреть в сторону No SQL решений?

PS Извините, короче никак не получилось описать данную проблему, но проблема на мой взгляд очень интересная.

Comment: Умпоминают похожий кейс [на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764366/mysql-force-index-use-cases) — когда  есть  `JOIN`'ы плюс `WHERE` по полю типа DATE, MySQL предпочитал PK и FK индексу по дате, поэтому `FORCE INDEX` заметно спасал.

В комментах к доке пишут, что если поставить условие по нужному полю первым в WHERE, то задействуется индекс по этому полю. Может, попробовать добавить пустое условие вроде `WHERE n_publ_date > 0`?

Comment: Старенькая статья, но тем не менее стоит почитать - http://www.mysqldiary.com/the-battle-between-force-index-and-the-query-optimizer/

Что касается объёма данных - сущие копейки, если честно. На сегодняшний день и 40kk уже не так много. Уходить в NO SQL решения смысла никакого.

Comment: Каким образом тогда обрабатывают данные такие компании как google yandex? ;)

Comment: Используют другие сервера и мощные сервера. Плюс кэширование и т.д и т.п.

Comment: >> такие компании как google yandex

шардинг?

Comment: Шардинг конечно круто.

И все таки, хотел писать свой небольшой фреймворк, и теперь просто мозг взрывается как спроектировать базу, в силу особенностей SQL, склоняюсь к тому, что не будет никакой нормализации, все будет в одной таблице xD 
Но тогда отпадает связь многие-ко-многим. мда...

Answer (score 1):

Умпоминают похожий кейс [на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764366/mysql-force-index-use-cases) — когда  есть  `JOIN`'ы плюс `WHERE` по полю типа DATE, MySQL предпочитал PK и FK индексу по дате, поэтому `FORCE INDEX` заметно спасал.

В комментах к доке [пишут](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html), что если поставить условие по нужному полю первым в WHERE, то задействуется индекс по этому полю. Может, попробовать добавить пустое условие вроде `WHERE n_publ_date > 0`?

Был даже похожий [багрепорт](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52849), который связывали с преобразованием типов. И баг починен. У вас свежая версия MySQL?

Comment: Попробовал поставить условие n_publ_date > 0, картина никак не изменилась.

Пользуюсь openserver'ом изначально стояла MySQL 5.1.67, после того как поставил 5.6.10, время выполнения увеличилось в 2 раза и force index перестал работать ^__^

Самое интересное что не только index datetime не цепляется, но в принципе и любой другой, sql оптимизатор в любом случае выбирает первичные/вторичные ключи

Comment: А попробуйте поставить `optimizer_prune_level=0` ([что это](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_optimizer_prune_level)) — изменится explain?

Comment: в конфиге нету такого параметра, куда его добавить?

Comment: [`my.cnf`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html), в секцию `[mysqld]`, наверное. Сам не пробовал.